# How to get revtex4-2 running in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

After downloading the file revtex-tds-2020-10-22.zip from https://journals.aps.org/revtex,
what should be done to get revtex4-2 up and running in Ubuntu 22.04?
Where exactly should one unzip the revtex4-2-tds.zip  file?
After several trials, I keep getting the following error message which
I fail to understand (my files compile with no error in older revtex
implementations)

`! Extra \endgroup. \document ->\endgroup`
    `\document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {begindo...`
 `l.74 \begin{document}`

latex --version  returns the following:

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by installing the full dependency of texlive, that is running `apt install texlive-full`. There is a way to install a single packages (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages) but I had other errors using the installer.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to install texlive-publishers.